# Invalid event in x11

Tags: x11

I use [xscope](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/xscope.1.xhtml) to monitor X11 protocol. I monitor X11 protocol because I try to fix some focus issue with Swing and MPX. I noticed that following packet is transmitted when focus error occurs. How to draw a conclusion from this message? I still don't know what is invalid. Do you have any idea?

```
614.21:                                           32 bytes <-- X11 Server

Read from fd 8
a1 20 c2 
0b 07 00 c0 00 68 01 00 00 71 01 00 00 21 9f 6a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00                                                       Event (fd 8): a1 20 c2 
0b 07 00 c0 00 68 01 00 00 71 01 00 00 21 9f 6a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 
                                         ..............EVENT: **INVALID** (161)
                                                      format: 20
                                             sequence number: 0bc2
                                                      window: WIN 00c00007
                                                        type: ATM 00000168 <WM_PROTOCOLS>
                                                        data: 71 01 00 00 21 9f 
                                                            : 6a 01 00 00 00 00 
                                                            : 00 00 00 00 00 00 
                                                            : 00 00 
Have 0 need 32
```

**=====EDIT=====**

I suppose that there is some error between client (my application) and Window Manager. I think so because there is `<WM_PROTOCOLS>`.

Answer (score 0):

xscope 1.4 and earlier have a bug that cause it to print that INVALID output for events sent by another client via a SendEvent request, which causes the 8th bit of the event id to be sent.  That's actually a `ClientMessage` event (161 - 128 = 33, which is the event code for `ClientMessage`).

[This is fixed](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xscope/commit/?id=73c82c6b983e39e24f49c2c794d654bd349309d3) in [xscope 1.4.1](https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-announce/2014-June/002443.html).